# How to run a DHCP server on an ethernet port of a MacBook successfully?

Tags: macos, unix, dhcp, raspberry-pi

I aim to have an ethernet switch on my MacBook ethernet port from which I will have several Raspberry Pi's connected getting their IP via DHCP, each will have a VNC server running on them for remote access and I want my internet to be shared to them from my MacBook's WiFi connection.

**In order to do this I have made use of OSX's inbuilt DHCP server as follows:**

- Edited bootpd.plist in /etc/, this configures the DHCP server for the
  192.168.2.0 network

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>Subnets</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
      <key>_creator</key>
      <string>com.apple.InternetSharing</string>
      <key>allocate</key>
      <true/>
      <key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
          <array>
              <string>192.168.2.1</string>
          </array>
      <key>dhcp_router</key>
          <string>192.168.2.1</string>
      <key>lease_max</key>
          <integer>36000</integer>
      <key>lease_min</key>
          <integer>36000</integer>
      <key>name</key>
          <string>192.168.2/24</string>
      <key>net_address</key>
          <string>192.168.2.0</string>
      <key>net_mask</key>
          <string>255.255.255.0</string>
      <key>net_range</key>
          <array>
              <string>192.168.2.2</string>
              <string>192.168.2.254</string>
          </array>
      </dict>
  </array>
  <key>bootp_enabled</key>
      <false/>
  <key>detect_other_dhcp_server</key>
      <true/>
  <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
      <array>
          <string>bridge0</string>
      </array>
  <key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
      <false/>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```
- Edited/created bootptab in /etc/, this assigns static IP's to the
  Raspberry Pi's

```
%%
# hostname      hwtype  hwaddr              ipaddr          bootfile
Raspi1          1       aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:f1   192.168.2.2
Raspi2          1       aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:f2   192.168.2.3
Raspi3          1       aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:f3   192.168.2.4
Raspi4          1       aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:f4   192.168.2.5
```

- Run/Stop the DHCP server using the following commands, created an
  alias in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias dhcp-start='sudo /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist'
alias dhcp-stop='sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist'
```

**Great I'm able to connect to each Pi remotely, but I have the following problems:**

1. Unable to connect to internet from each Pi, given I have shared the internet connection from WiFi to the ethernet port within OSX's sharing menu:

   [image: Internet Sharing in OSX]
2. Upon reset of the MacBook the bootpd.plist file is being deleted

Any help in solving the above two issues appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you actually set up Internet sharing. Did you?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Yes I did, I've added a screenshot to show this now

Comment: how would you configure the ethernet connection in Preferences/Network ?

Comment: Lock the bootd.plist?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, your Internet sharing might be interfering with your `bootd` configuration, specially given that you're assigning static addresses to the Raspberry πs.

Once you have the dhcp server running, you can create routes for them. If your wifi is on `en1`, and we assume your gateway for `en1` is `172.16.0.1`, you could do something like

```
sudo route add 192.168.2.0/24 172.16.0.1
```

which will cause packets coming from `192.168.2.0` to `192.168.2.255` to go through your wifi's gateway.

See, for instance, [Add a permanent static route to Mac OS X](http://meinit.nl/add-permanent-static-route-mac-os-x)
 on how to automate it.